# What is this schematic symbol? (Circled B with four diagonal hatches)

Tags: schematics

[image]

(It's not on the [wiki page for electronic symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_symbol), or this [sparkfun page with lots of symbols](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-read-a-schematic/all).)

Comment: Could it be a light bulb? In what context have you seen this?

Comment: I guess it's possible. +24 V DC --> contactor relay --> this --> 0V

Comment: **B**linker, maybe?

Comment: This is closest to an IEEE symbol for a terminal (as in connector type). Without context, hard to say.  Unfortunately, people are ignoring standard symbols and reference designators (fighting this at work) and making up their own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The symbol is for a lamp (with rays of light eminating from it).
- The 'B' is, most likely, for 'blue'. This would be typical for an industrial machine reset button.
- The dotted line would usually be connected to a switch contact indicating that the lamp is part of an illuminated button.

I can't find a reference for the symbol but it's quite common on American machine ladder schematics that I have seen.

[image]

*Figure 1. Indicator lamps on a ladder diagram. Image source: [All About Circuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-6/permissive-interlock-circuits/).*

Comment: This is correct. Used for many years in industry.